# No automatic "NA" writing (mtext) of spearman value into plot

Tags: r, plot, na

I want to insert a spearman correlation into an empty plot. 
At the moment I am doing this with mtext(…), but I am having a problem when no correlation can be calculated. In this case an “NA” arises (both in result for Spearman AND also in the plot as NA without “).

How to omit SHOWING the NAs  in the plots?

> ```
> newcor<- (cor(twocolumndata,method=c("spearman")) 
>  # as there are 2 values newcor has to be specified >newcor[2]
>
> plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),type = "n", xaxt='n', yaxt='n',xlab='n') # Empty Plot
> mtext(newcor[2])#insert text (I left out here the positional infos)
> ```

additional info:
- this plot will go into a 10 times 10 plot, thus it needs to be automatic.
- na.omit did not work here, I thought it might be due to the fact NA migh be caracter

Thank you R-people!
Julia

Answer (score 1):

What about using an `if` statement:

```
if(!is.na(newcor[2])) mtext(.....)
```